# Limit Kindle Fire emulator of using xlarge-mdpi resources?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-resources, kindle-fire

If I have two resource directories:

- `res/drawable-large-mdpi` and
- `res/drawable-xlarge-mdpi`

then Kindle Fire emulator made by Amazon's specs will always use resources from the later directory.

The reason is known: emulator calculates Fire's screen as `xlarge-mdpi` although in reality it is `large-mdpi`.

How can I have both resource directories and force Fire to use resources from `res/drawable-large-mdpi`, while letting other 10-inch tablets use resources from `res/drawable-xlarge-mdpi`? I am trying to solve this for days with no success.

PS. I do not have a real device but I do testing for Kindle Fire via emulator created by Amazon's specifications.

Comment: If you use an actual device it will pull from large-mdpi, what does it matter what the emulator does?

Comment: @HandlerExploit The problem is that I do not have it. I do testing for Kindle Fire via emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I have both resource directories and force Fire to use resources from res/drawable-large-mdpi, while letting other 10-inch tablets use resources from res/drawable-xlarge-mdpi?

It already does this, so your work is done.

However, probably you will need to buy a Fire to test it. You cannot create a 2.3.x emulator image that faithfully reproduces the Fire in this respect.

You should be able to create a newer emulator (e.g., 3.2 or 4.0) that should work, though I have not tried this. They fixed the emulator calculations to handle this case better some time after 2.3.

Comment: So buying is the only option. Too bad. however, I did tested it on 2.3.3 (which has the calculations issue) and haven't tried newer Android versions. I wanted to look as close as the original. I will test this asap and report the result here. Thanks! Again...

Comment: This worked. Android 4.0.3 emulator made on Amazon's specs recognises the emulator correctly. so no need to buy a real device :)

Comment: @sandalone: There are more differences in the Fire than simply the screen size, such as the collapsible "system bar" for HOME, MENU, etc. The Fire does not meet Google's compatibility requirements -- the ones that help ensure our apps run faithfully on devices that have the Play Store. Personally, I would be hesitant to release an app for Fire users without actually testing it on the Fire. That being said, it's your app, and you are welcome to do as you wish.